# How to set custom font in JavaFX?

Tags: java, css, javafx

I'm trying to set the custom font "Cerebri Sans Regular" to my JavaFX application. I'm using Java SE 11 and JavaFX 11.

My tries:

```
public class SampleController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label customFont;
    
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        Font font = Font.loadFont("cerebrisans-regular.ttf", 20);
        
        customFont.setFont(font);
    }
    
}
```

Error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.text.Font.getNativeFont()" because "<parameter1>" is null
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.text.Font$1.getNativeFont(Font.java:68)
```

Another try from css

```
@font-face {
    src: url("cerebrisans-regular.ttf");
}

.root {
    -fx-background-color: gray;
    -fx-font-family: "Cerebri Sans"; /* this name is from font file */
}

.customFont {
    -fx-text-fill: red;
    -fx-font-size: 16px;
    -fx-font-family: "Cerebri Sans";
}
```

Error

```
Mar 03, 2021 2:31:56 PM com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager loadStylesheetUnPrivileged
INFO: Could not load @font-face font [file:/C:/Java%20Training/JavaFX-Test/Custom-Font-Demo/bin/application/cerebrisans-regular.ttf]
```

Comment: Are you missing a semicolon on the ```src: url("cerebrisans-regular.ttf")``` line in your CSS file?

Comment: @Ryan I  have updated the question and the error has changed.

Comment: Ok, have you taken a look at this question: [“loadStylesheetUnPrivileged” error when trying to use css stylesheet with JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33764821/4748172)?

Comment: @Ryan Yes. I have tried them in my code, either adding stylesheets to fxml or root.getStyleSheet()... and both. Not working. Same error.

Comment: I got this. Thanks for your help. In my working environment name, there was a space and it is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my working environment name, there was a space. Removed, renamed and now it is working with the CSS code shown in the question.